# Calculate needed spaces in Jinja2 / Ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-2.x

I'm trying to calculate the needed space based on the longest word in a dictionary.

It seems though that the variable `num` doesn't transfer it's value to the second inner loop.

I'm basically trying to caculate the amount of spaces to align the columns correctly.

```
{% for module in modules %}
module "{{ module.name }}" {
  source = "{{ module.source }}"
  {% set num = 1 %}
{% for n in module.vars.keys() %}
  {% if  num < n|length %}
    {% set num = n|length %}
  {% endif %}
    {{ num }}: {{ n }} 
{% endfor %}
{% for m in module.vars %}
    {{ num }}
  {{ m }} {{ '= "' + module.vars[m]|indent(width=num) }}"
{% endfor %}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, you can't get variables out of loops this way. See "Scoping behavior" in the [docs](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#assignments).

One option is to use what they suggest and create a namespace:

```
{% set ns = namespace(num=0) %}
{% for n in module.vars.keys() %}
  {% if ns.num < n|length %}
    {% set ns.num = n|length %}
  {% endif %}
    {{ ns.num }}: {{ n }} 
{% endfor %}
```

In your case, there is an easier and cleaner solution though: you can calculate the maximum width in an expression. Use `map()` to get a list of lengths, and use `max` filter to get the biggest one:

```
{% set indent_width = module.vars.keys() | map("length") | max %}
{% for m in module.vars %}
   {{ m }} {{ '= "' + module.vars[m]|indent(width=indent_width) }}"
{% endfor %}
```